# Problema con error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php

me sale un error cuando voy a ejecutar mi codigo , es el siguiente :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php on line 61

Number of books found :
```

Este es el formulario HTML :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Book-O-Rama</title>
</head>

<body>
 <blockquote>
   <blockquote>
     <blockquote>
       <h1>Book-O-Rama Catalog Search</h1>
        </blockquote>
      </blockquote>
</blockquote>

<form action="results.php" method="post">

<p>Chosse search Type :</p>
<p><select name="searchtype">
 <option value="author">Author</option>
 <option value="title">Title</option>
 <option value="isnb">ISNB</option>
</select></p>

<p>Enter search term :</p>

<input name="searchterm" type="text">

<p><input type="submit" value="Search"></p>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el codigo en PHP :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Results</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
 
 // Defino nombre de las variables
 // searchtype : Tipo de busqueda
 // searchterm : Termino de busqueda
 $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];  // Recibo los nombres de las variables de los formularios
 $searchterm=$_POST['searchterm'];
 $searchterm=trim($searchterm);  // funcion trim() : Elimina espacios en blanco introducidos involuntariamente con el usuario
 
 if(!$searchtype || !$searchterm){  // Comprobacion de datos que tienen que introducirse , por temas de seguridad
  echo 'You have not entered search details. Please go to back and try again.'; /* No ha ingresado los detalles de búsqueda. Por favor, ve hacia atrás y vuelve a intentarlo */
  exit;
 }
 
 if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){  // Funcion vieja , desabilitada en el nuevo PHP 6 , nos indica si las comillas se añaden automaticamente o no , si no se añaden , utilizamos addslashes para escapar
  $searchtype=addslashes($searchtype);  // Se deben filtrar los datos para enviar a una BD
  $searchterm=addslashes($searchterm);
 }
 
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "books";

 
@ $db= new MySQLi($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); /* HOST,NOMBRE DE USUARIO,CONTRA,NOMBRE DE LA BD */
 // Esta funcion crea una instancia de la clase mysqli
 
 //$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
 
 if ($db->connect_error) {  // Compruebo el intento de conexion
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error); // Devuelve el numero de error ( en caso que lo hubiera )
} 

 
 $sql="select * from books where ".$searchtype."like'%".$searchterm."%'"; // Buscamos el valor 
 $result=$db->query($sql);   // Ejecuto la consulta , devuelve un objeto de resultados

 
 $num_results = $result->num_rows;  // Devuelve el numero de filas , de la forma orientada a 
 
 echo '<p> Number of books found : ' . $num_results.'</p>';
 
 for($i=0; $i<$num_results;$i++)
 {
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  //   Obtiene una fila de resultado como un array asociativo
  echo '<p><strong>'.($i+1).'.Title : ';
  echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title'])); 
  echo '<strong><br />Author: ';
  echo stripslashes($row['author']);
  echo '<br /> ISNB: ';
  echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
  echo '<br />Price: ';
  echo stripslashes($row['price']);
  echo '</p>';
 }
 
 //$result->free(); // Libera la memoria asociada a un resultado
 $db->close();  // Cierra la conexion previamente abierta en la BD
 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el codigo original sacado del libro :

[image: Codigo Libro]

Gracias de antemano , soy nuevo en stackoverflow

Saludos !

Comment: No está encontrado registros. Imprime la consulta: `echo $sql;` copia el resultado y prueba a ejecutarla directamente en el manejador de base de datos. Por otra parte, tu código es bastante mejorable en varios puntos, sobre todo en dos que son cruciales: **seguridad**  (no usas consultas preparadas) y **rendimiento** (es mejor leer los datos dentro de un `while`... además habrá más claridad en el código). Pero veamos primero por qué no funciona, como primer paso depura tu consulta. Ahh, y quita la `@`, su uso es una mala práctica, dificulta depurar el código al silenciar los errores.

Comment: Hola , primero que nada agradezco tu respuesta . Este codigo lo saque de un libro

Comment: Imagino que será un libro algo antiguo... ¿?  Cada vez que veo el uso de `@` en el código, no sé por qué, pienso en código antiguo y obsoleto. Ahora bien, si el libro te enseña a programar mal, considera aprender de otras fuentes, hoy día en la red hay excelentes manuales y tutoriales para aprender, y sitios como este en el que alguien te puede decir, *eso es mejorable*. Te propondré un código mejorado, y seguro.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano , la respuesta anterior era mas extensa , pero stackoverflow no me dejo editarla . En fin , lo saque del libro " Desarrollo web con PHP y MySQL" de Luke Welling , pagina 312 . Ahora probare lo que me indicas y estare avisando mi resultado . Saludos !

Comment: @Chehin Bienvenido! Ya que eres nuevo te comento que puedes editar cuantas veces quieras y/o necesites tus preguntas, los comentarios son editables durante 5 minutos. Luego tendrías que borrarlos y crear uno nuevo si consideras que el texto está mal. Por tanto, si consideras que puedes añadir información útil a la pregunta, no dudes en editarla y mejorarla, eso siempre es de agradecer.

Answer (score 2):

Propongo este código, aplicando algunos de los conceptos indicados en comentarios. No lo he documentado como hubiera querido por falta de tiempo...

Si hay algo que no entiendes del código, lo puedes preguntar en comentarios.

Básicamente:

- Recojo en una variable todos los errores posibles del código.
- Quito el uso de `@` por ser una mala práctica. Hace la depuración muy difícil.
- Aplico consultas preparadas (seguridad en el código y en el sistema). La Inyección SQL supone un alto riesgo no sólo a nivel de la base de datos. Cuando tengas tiempo documéntate sobre el asunto, aquí mismo hay información muy buena sobre el tema.
- Establezco un control estricto del código, para que el mismo no sea *mudo*  ante eventuales fallos.

Aquí lo dejo, creo no haber cometido ningún error. Espero te sirva.

```
$db= new MySQLi($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); /* HOST,NOMBRE DE USUARIO,CONTRA,NOMBRE DE LA BD */
// Esta funcion crea una instancia de la clase mysqli

$arrResultado=array();

if ($db->connect_error) {
    $arrResultado["mensaje"]="Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error; // Devuelve el numero de error ( en caso que lo hubiera )
}else{

    $sql="select title, author, isbn, price from books where ".$searchtype." like ?"; // Buscamos el valor

    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);

    if ($stmt){
        $strLIKE="%".$searchterm."%";
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $strLIKE);
        $stmt->execute();

        $num_results = $stmt->num_rows;  // Devuelve el numero de filas , de la forma orientada a

        if ($num_results){
            echo '<p> Number of books found : ' . $num_results.'</p>';
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($titulo, $autor, $isbn, $precio);
            $i=1;
            while ($stmt->fetch())
            {

                echo '<p><strong>'.($i).'.Title : ';
                echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($titulo);
                echo '<strong><br />Author: ';
                echo stripslashes($autor);
                echo '<br /> ISNB: ';
                echo stripslashes($isbn);
                echo '<br />Price: ';
                echo stripslashes($precio);
                echo '</p>';
                $i++;

            }

        }else{
            $arrResultado['mensaje']='No se encontraron filas en los resultados';
        }

        $stmt->close(); // Libera la memoria asociada a un resultado

    }else{

        $arrResultado['mensaje']='Error :'.$stmt->error;

    }

    $db->close();  // Cierra la conexion previamente abierta en la BD

}

if ($arrResultado){

    echo $arrResultado["mensaje"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable result no es un objeto ya que la consulta SQL está incorrecta. ya que al hacer la concatenacion 
de  $searchtype la consulta queda mal por qué no hay espacio de separación antes del like.

Debes corregir la consulta SQL y validar que $result sea diferente de false antes de hacer uso de la variable.

Si la consulta no trae resultados no tendrías ese tipo de error. El rpblema es de sintaxis SQL.

Comment: Hola sergio , gracias por tu respuesta . El codigo lo saque de el libro " Desarrollo web con PHP y MySQL" de Luke Welling , pagina 312 . Ahora probare tu respuesta y aviso el resultado . Saludos !